# html canvas -- position in front/back?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Javascript newbie question -- I have the following.  It draws my rectangle just fine, but always in back.  How can I move it to the front?

Javascript:

```
function happycode() {
    var element = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = element.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle="#FF7700";
    context.fillRect(900, 200, 300, 300);
};
```

HTML:

```
<body onload=happycode();>
     // lots of elements here
    <canvas position="absolute" id="myCanvas"width="2000px"height="1000px"z-index=1000></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first off `width="2000px"height="1000px"` is incorrect, it should just be `width="2000" height="1000"`

`position="absolute"` and `z-index=1000` are also incorrect, you are trying to write CSS style attributes as if they were a canvas attributes. You need to write this:

`<canvas id="myCanvas" width="2000" height="1000" style="z-index:1000; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></canvas>`

And that will give you what you want. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/FpDe6/

---

Note here that the width and height of the canvas are canvas attributes and *not* CSS attributes. This is kind of unique and confuses a lot of canvas newcomers.

If you set the CSS width/height to some pixel value you will not be changing the size of the canvas itself, but instead stretching the canvas and making things look very weird.

So just to be clear, this is good, and will make a 500x500 canvas:

`<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>`

This is bad, and will make a default canvas (300x150) and stretch it to 500x500, making everything look weirdly scaled:

`<canvas id="myCanvas" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></canvas>`